# Apache Redirecting outside of DocumentRoot

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a file structure as follows:

```
- Site
  - includes
    - page.php
  - pages
    - example.php
  - public
    - .htaccess
```

**.htaccess** uses rewrite_module to resolve most requests to page.php.

```
RewriteRule ^ "../includes/page.php" [L]
```

**page.php** parses the original request and includes the proper "page" from the pages directory.

I want initial requests to resolve to /Site/public, so I have the following apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        DocumentRoot /Site/public
</VirtualHost>
```

This yields 400 Bad Request errors because I'm attempting to redirect to a file outside of DocumentRoot.

I ultimately don't want a user to be able to directly access files outside of public.

Is there a good way to specify that, in terms of execution, /Site is the root, but in terms of serving /Site/public is the root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty common.

Instead of using .htaccess as a router, you should use PHP.

Edit: You CANNOT use .htaccess to route pages outside of docroot.

Keep most your files outside of the docroot, but keep index.php that handles the routing. PHP is able to include/require files outside of the docroot, and this  is used pretty extensively in a few PHP frameworks.

```
- Site
  - includes
    - page.php
  - pages
    - example.php
  - public
    - .htaccess
    - index.php ( <?php require_once('../includes/page.php'); ?>
```

Comment: I thought it was common! Sounds like the trick is to basically have page.php inside of public, then?